# How to set admin login rights to that specific page with Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, ms-access

I figure out that there's some minor error that I don't know when I login via admin. It just keep redirecting me to Page404.aspx. Anyone can correct my errors? Help appreciated !

Background information: For MS Access Database - It is `CUsername, @eUsername` possible due to Register page

Additional information: Register of account and login plus update customer page works fine totally. except the UpdateProductsAdmin page which i want it for only username with "admin" logged in.

```
  cmd.paramters.add.withvalue
  string strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO "
        + "myCustomer (CFirstName, CLastName, CAddressLine1, CAddressLine2, CCountry,  CState, CPostalCode, CContactNumber, CEmail, CConfirmEmail, CUserName, CPassword, CConfirmPassword)" 
        + "VALUES (@eFirstName, @eLastName, @eAddressLine1, @eAddressLine2, @eCountry, @eState, @ePostalCode, @eContactNumber, @eEmail, @eConfirmEmail, @eUserName, @ePassword, @eConfirmPassword)";

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class UpdateProductsAdmin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
        mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/webBase.accdb");
        mDB.Open();
        Type csType = this.GetType();
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataReader rdr;
        string strSQLSelect = "SELECT CUsername FROM myCustomer ORDER BY CUsername";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read() == true) 
        {
            if (Session["CUsername"] == "admin")
            {
                DetailsView1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Page404.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my Account's page, im trying to use the logic here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class Account : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string UFlag = "F"; public string strUserName;
    static readonly string ScriptSuccessUpdate = "<script language=\"javascript\"\n" + "alert (\"Update successful - Please surf to other pages to shop\");\n </script>";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelUserName.Text = (string)Session["sUserName"];
        LabelFirstName.Text = (string)Session["sFirstName"];
        LabelLastName.Text = (string)Session["sLastName"];
        LabelAddressLine1.Text = (string)Session["sAddressLine1"];
        LabelAddressLine2.Text = (string)Session["sAddressLine2"];
        LabelCountry.Text = (string)Session["sCountry"];
        LabelState.Text = (string)Session["sState"];
        LabelPostalCode.Text = (string)Session["sPostalCode"];
        LabelContactNumber.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sContactNumber"]).ToString();
        LabelEmail.Text = (string)Session["sEmail"];
        LabelPassword.Text = (string)Session["sPassword"];

    }
    protected void ImageButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        strUserName = (string)Session["sUserName"];
        if (TextBoxFirstName.Text!="")
        {
            string StrFName = "CFirstName"; string strFValue = TextBoxFirstName.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(StrFName, strFValue);
            Session["sFirstName"] = TextBoxFirstName.Text;
        }
        if (TextBoxLastName.Text!="")
        {
            string strFName = "CLastName"; string strFValue = TextBoxLastName.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
            Session["sLastName"] = TextBoxLastName.Text;
        }
        if (TextBoxAddressLine1.Text != "")
        {
            string strFName = "CAddressLine1"; string strFValue = TextBoxAddressLine1.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
            Session["sAddressLine1"] = TextBoxAddressLine1.Text;
        }
        if (TextBoxAddressLine2.Text != "")
        {
            string strFName = "CAddressLine2"; string strFValue = TextBoxAddressLine2.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
            Session["sAddressLine2"] = TextBoxAddressLine2.Text;
        }
        if (TextBoxCountry.Text != "")
        {
            string strFName = "CCountry"; string strFValue = TextBoxCountry.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
            Session["sCountry"] = TextBoxCountry.Text;
        }
        if (TextBoxState.Text != "")
        {
            string strFName = "CState"; string strFValue = TextBoxState.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
            Session["sState"] = TextBoxState.Text;
        }
        if (TextBoxPostalCode.Text != "")
        {
            string strFName = "CPostalCode"; string strFValue = TextBoxPostalCode.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
            Session["sPostalCode"] = TextBoxPostalCode.Text;
        }
        if (TextBoxContactNumber.Text != "")
        {
            string strFName = "CContactNumber"; string strFValue = TextBoxContactNumber.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
            Session["sContactNumber"] = TextBoxContactNumber.Text;
        }
        if (TextBoxEmail.Text != "")
        {
            string strFName = "CEmail"; string strFValue = TextBoxEmail.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
            Session["sEmail"] = TextBoxEmail.Text;
        }
        if (TextBoxPassword.Text != "")
        {
            string strFName = "CPassword"; string strFValue = TextBoxPassword.Text;
            UpdatemyCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
            Session["sPassword"] = TextBoxPassword.Text;
        }
        if (UFlag == "T")
        {
            Type strType = this.GetType();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(strType, "Success", ScriptSuccessUpdate);
        }
    }
    public void UpdatemyCustomer(string strFName, string strFValue)
    {
        OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
        mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/webBase.accdb");
        mDB.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        String strSQL = "UPDATE myCustomer SET " + strFName + "=@newValue WHERE cUserName = @eUserName";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, mDB);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@newValue", OleDbType.Char).Value = strFValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@eUserName", OleDbType.Char).Value = strUserName;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        UFlag = "T";
        mDB.Close();
    }
}
```

For register of account.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static readonly string scriptErrorUserId =
        "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
        "alert (\"Error - UserID you entered is taken up, please key in another UserID\");\n" +
    "</script>";

    static readonly string scriptSuccessNewAccount =
    "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
        "alert (\"Your account has been successfully created - Thank you!\");\n" +
    "</script>";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
        mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/webBase.accdb");
        mDB.Open();
        Type csType = this.GetType();
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataReader rdr;
        string strSQLSelect = "SELECT CUsername FROM myCustomer ORDER BY CUsername";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read()==true)
        {
            if (TextBoxUserName.Text == (string)rdr["cUsername"]) 
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType,"Error",scriptErrorUserId);
                mDB.Close();
                return;
            }
        }

        // Insert new records keyed by the user
        string strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO "
            + "myCustomer (CFirstName, CLastName, CAddressLine1, CAddressLine2, CCountry, CState, CPostalCode, CContactNumber, CEmail, CConfirmEmail, CUserName, CPassword, CConfirmPassword)"
            + "VALUES (@eFirstName, @eLastName, @eAddressLine1, @eAddressLine2, @eCountry, @eState, @ePostalCode, @eContactNumber, @eEmail, @eConfirmEmail, @eUserName, @ePassword, @eConfirmPassword)";

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLInsert, mDB);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eFirstName", TextBoxFirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eLastName", TextBoxLastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eAddressLine1", TextBoxAddressLine1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eAddressLine2", TextBoxAddressLine2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eCountry", TextBoxCountry.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eState", TextBoxState.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ePostalCode", TextBoxPostalCode.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eContactNumber", TextBoxContactNumber.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eEmail", TextBoxEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eConfirmEmail", TextBoxConfirmEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eUserName", TextBoxUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ePassword", TextBoxPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eConfirmPassword", TextBoxConfirmPassword.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mDB.Close();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Success", scriptSuccessNewAccount);
        Response.Redirect("Account.aspx");

        // prepare Session Variables for newly registered customer
        Session["sFlag"] = "T";
        Session["sFirstName"] = (string)TextBoxFirstName.Text;
        Session["sLastName"] = (string)TextBoxLastName.Text;
        Session["sAddressLine1"] = (string)TextBoxAddressLine1.Text;
        Session["sAddressLine2"] = (string)TextBoxAddressLine2.Text;
        Session["sCountry"] = (string)TextBoxCountry.Text;
        Session["sState"] = (string)TextBoxState.Text;
        Session["sPostalCode"] = (string)TextBoxPostalCode.Text;
        Session["sContactNumber"] = (string)TextBoxContactNumber.Text;
        Session["sEmail"] = (string)TextBoxEmail.Text;
        Session["sConfirmEmail"] = (string)TextBoxConfirmEmail.Text;
        Session["sUserName"] = (string)TextBoxUserName.Text;
        Session["sePassword"] = (string)TextBoxPassword.Text;
        Session["sConfirmPassword"] = (string)TextBoxConfirmPassword.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Code , I'm not see Where is Init the Session of Session["CUsername"]

And In Your SQL CMD, IF First Row CUsername is not admin . you will always Get **False**

so you will Redirect to "Page404.aspx"

You can Write this ensure you can get right SQL Query Result

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq; using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI; 
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    public partial class UpdateProductsAdmin : System.Web.UI.Page 
    { 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     { 
         if ((string)Session["sUsername"] == "admin") 
            { 
              DetailsView1.Visible = true; 
           } 
            else { 
              Response.Redirect("Page404.aspx"); 
            } 

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of?
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CuserName", [YourLoginID]);
and what is YourLoginID?

Comment: Parameter is your SQLCMD Variable . Like This -> SELECT UserName FROM Customer WHERE UserName=@UserName .  And if you add Parameters 

cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", LoginTextBox.Text); 

LoginTextBox.Text ='John' The CMD in Execution will be replace - >
 
SELECT UserName FROM Customer WHERE UserName='John' .

It's can ensure you always get 1 rows (if user is Exist) or 0 rows

in your SQLCMD , if myCustomer has 1000 user , you will always get 

1000 rows and to do your IF expression

Comment: But this is not the masterpage so I cannot use textboxUsername.text uh. Any other roundabouts? I don't think there's a need for cmd.paramaters.add uh.

Comment: Actually I just want a simple one
Maybe I can use sFlag must be "T" // stands for users logged in, in my codes
Like if session["cUsername"] equal "admin, display detailsview, else response redirect. any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe 
if ((string)Session["sFlag"]!="T" && (String)Session["CUsername"]!="admin")
{ 
display detailsview
}
else
response redirect

Comment: In ASP.NET , if you want getting Authenticated User . You can use this --> '     if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
            if (User.Identity.Name == "admin")
            {
                DetailsView1.Visible = true;
                //Initial Session if you want 
                Session["CUsername"] = User.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Page404.aspx");
            }
        }'

Comment: Do i need to open oledbconnection if i just use this way? or the rdr?

Comment: No you don't need , User.Identity is ASP.NET HttpContext provider User Property . You can try it . : )

Comment: Can you show a full Login example code 

or ref this hyperlink about User.Identity [Get Username for logged in user](http://forums.asp.net/t/1179997.aspx?Get+Username+for+logged+in+user)

Comment: King JK! Re see post i Posted!!

Comment: Hi do you mind if there's a way to contact you cause I kinda need help urgently on this. I would very much appreciate it if you could add me on facebook and chat me up! 
https://www.facebook.com/kayzelmoo !

Comment: OKay, I'm added u , My name is KingJK
Btw. in your account.aspx . prepare Session Variables block will not execute , because you exec **Response.Redirect("Account.aspx")** before prepare Session Variables